# Perl while loop / reading file

Tags: perl

I'm new to Perl and I have a problem when reading a file line by line. I started with a tutorial which suggested using a while loop. That worked fine, however I wanted to have an option to break out of the loop in case of an error. I know I can use the "last" keyword, but I don't like that very much, I would like to include it in the while loop's boolean expression so it is easier to see on what conditions it stops. So I did

```
$error=0;
while ( (!$error) && (<MYFILE>) ) {
print $_;
...    
}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work because $_ seems to contain a "uninitialized value". For some reason, when I change (!$error) to (!0), it works again. I would understand that it was not working had I used || because of lazy evaluation, but with && in this case both sides need to be evaluated so I don't understand why it doesn't initialize the line variable.

Comment: Learn the idioms of the language you are learning (any language) - and `last` is one of the idioms of Perl.

Comment: As I have stated in the question, I know about the last keyword.

Comment: Okay then, learn to *embrace* the idioms of the language.

Answer (score 5):

The magical assignment to `$_` only occurs if there is nothing else in the loop:

```
while (<MYFILE>) {
    print $_;
    ...    
}
```

If you want the error test too - which is not recommended - then you need to do the assignment:

```
my $error = 0;
while (!$error && ($_ = <MYFILE>)) {
    print;
    $error = 1 if m/quit/i;
}
```

Don't forget to add:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
```

The reason why the version with '`!0`' worked is probably because Perl optimizes and recognizes that '`!0`' is always true and removes it from the loop, leaving just the I/O operator, which then assigns to `$_`.

NB: it is far better to use idiomatic Perl and the `last` statement:

```
while (<MYFILE>) {
    print;
    last if m/quit/i;
}
```

Comment: I believe you need to add a "defined" check on $_ in the while loop condition, otherwise a line in the file containing "0" will evaluate as false and end the loop. So, something like: while (!$error && defined ($_ = <MYFILE>)) { ...

Comment: Ok, thanks, I didn't know about the nature of the loop. I thought it would improve readability if all conditions for the loop are in one place. At university, I was taught GOTO and - to a lesser extend - break statements are evil, so I have always tried to avoid them. But I will use the version you suggested.

Comment: @Matthew: no, you don't need to do that.  The line also contains a newline (to be removed by `chomp` when required).  I suppose if a file ends with newline followed by 0 (and no trailing newline), then you might be correct - but that's not a standard text file.

Comment: @Matthew Wilson: The `defined` check is done automatically. See http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#I/O-Operators

Answer (score 3):

First, as Jonathan points out you should always write languages idiomatically unless you have a very good reason and here you don't.

Your larger problem is misunderstanding the `while` loop.  The automatic assignment of the result of the angle operator to `$_` only occurs if it is the only thing in the `while` conditional test.  If there are multiple items in the conditional test they are evaluated and then discarded (*Programming Perl* pp. 80-81 and [I/O Operators at Perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#I%2fO-Operators)).